# White space using GridSpec and right colorbar with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to make a figure with 2 subplots.

[image]

The problem is that on the right of the first figure, there is a whitespace (which belongs to the subplot below). Is is possible to make the first subplot to fit the entire space on the right ?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

data1 = np.random.rand(10,10)
data2 = np.random.rand(10,10)

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
gs = GridSpec(2,1,figure=fig)

ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])
img = plt.imshow(data1, aspect='auto')
plt.colorbar(location='bottom')

ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,0])
plt.imshow(data2)
plt.colorbar(location='right')
plt.axis("scaled")

plt.show()
```

Moreover, is it possible to have the right colorbar just next to the second plot ? As you can see here, the colorbar is at the far right.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you can do this (see the [colorbar placement guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/axes/colorbar_placement.html)). One option is to use the `pad` argument for the `colorbar` and manually shift the bottom `colorbar` location:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1 = np.random.rand(10,10)
data2 = np.random.rand(10,10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, constrained_layout=True)

img = ax[0].imshow(data1, aspect='auto')
fig.colorbar(img, location='bottom', ax=ax[0])

im2 = ax[1].imshow(data2)
fig.colorbar(
    im2,
    location='right',
    ax=ax[1],
    pad=-0.07,  # negative padding to shift the colorbar inwards
)
ax[1].axis("scaled")
```

which gives:

[image]

The other option is to use an [inset axes](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/axes/colorbar_placement.html#using-inset-axes) for the colorbar and setting the position of that manually:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, constrained_layout=True)

img = ax[0].imshow(data1, aspect='auto')
fig.colorbar(img, location='bottom', ax=ax[0])

im2 = ax[1].imshow(data2)
cax = ax[1].inset_axes(
    [17.5, 0, 0.75, 9],  # set the position in the data coordinates (xpos, ypos, xwidth, yheight)
    transform=ax[1].transData,
)
fig.colorbar(im2, cax=cax)
ax[1].axis("scaled")
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but do you know why the colorbar is far from the plot ?

Comment: Using `constrained_layout=True` does lots of automatic adjustments and moves things like the colorbar into what it considers the best position with respect to everything else. With my examples, you can manually move the colorbar about as much as you like, so it can be placed closer with, e.g., more negative padding. Alternatively, you could remove the use of `constrained_layout` completely.

Comment: Also, using `axis("scaled")` seems to shift the colorbar with respect to the main plot, but I don't know why that is. A lot of the matplotlib internals for automated relative figure placement are mysterious to me.

Comment: I used axis('scaled') because I wanted the second plot to be centered. Without this command, I don't know how to center all the plots.